# Sendto In Raw Socket

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, raw-sockets

the sendto function we have to pass destination struct sockaddr or sockaddr_in But what's the purpose?

isn't it, if we use raw Socket, we create our own header, which means we will specify the address directly in the header not in the sockaddr_in struct?

Does that mean we use sendto on raw socket is to determine which interface to use?

Comment: There are different types of "raw" sockets: raw IP sockets (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW) and device level packet interface (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW or SOCK_DGRAM). Which one do you mean?

Comment: (AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW) Sir

Comment: For (AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW) sendto() expects `struct sockaddr_ll` which describes interface to send from. See [man 7 packet](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html).

Comment: But sir how about the IPPROTO_RAW what socket address to forward to the sendto( )

Comment: As already answered below, for IPPROTO_RAW destination address in `sendto()` is required to resolve data link layer address. See also notes about IP_HDRINCL in [man 7 raw](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html). You can send an IP packet with destination address different from address used to route a packet.

Answer (score 0):

A raw IP socket contains only network layer information as target, i.e. IP address. To deliver the packet in the local network one also needs to have information for the lower layers, i.e. which network interface to use for sending, which MAC address to have as target at the link layer etc. The target IP address given in `sendto` is used to determine these information.